# Its me or my "3d" terraing is moving? LibGdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm having a bad time with this , i generate a 3d isometric terrain with the help of this site http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2032
i pass a perspective camera to the spriteBatch projectionMatrix but when i move my player(perspective camera follows my player) it seems like the terrains is moving look at this video of my game 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEMAo8F0qms&feature=youtu.be
i thinkg the terrain should be static! also i am using decalBatch my decals look wells they remain always in their position but the terrain not!

this is part of the code where i render terrain

```
    sb.setTransformMatrix(matrix);
    sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);//is perspective
    sb.begin();
    for(int z = 0; z < 100; z++) {
        for(int x = 0; x <80; x++) {
            sprites[x][z].draw(sb);
        }
    }
    sb.end()
```

here is the third person camera

```
    cam.lookAt(player.getX(), 0, player.getZ());

    cam.position.set(player.getX(),7f,player.getZ()-10f);

    playerDecal.setPosition(player.getX(), player.getY(), player.getZ());
```

my big problem is that terrain is not being static! is moving along with my cameras position.

Comment: Maybe it'd be better to post this question on the games stack exchange?

Comment: Looks totally fine in the video to me. Not sure what the problem is.